# Add row from table B to table A based on conditions

Tags: sql, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using python with sqlite. I have two datatables, table A and table B. I want to join the rows of table B with A on the following conditions:

- If a row occurs in B and not in A, add it to A.
- If a row occurs more in B than it occurs in A, add it to A until it occurs as often in A as it does in B.

If I have the following two tables

```
Table A  Table B
2 4 1 3  2 2 2 1
2 2 2 1  2 4 1 3
4 5 2 4  2 4 1 3
1 4 2 5  2 4 1 3
2 4 1 3  5 3 2 3
```

I want to have the following table

```
Table A + B
  2 2 2 1
  2 4 1 3
  2 4 1 3
  2 4 1 3
  4 5 2 4
  1 4 2 5
  5 3 2 3
```

**Question:** Is it possible to achieve this with an sql query? If so; how?

**Edit:** While the answers have proven very helpful they don't solve the entire question.

```
SELECT valB1, valB2, valB3, valB4 FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT valA1, valA2, valA3, valA4
             FROM A
             WHERE A.valA1 = B.valB1
               AND A.valA2 = B.valB2
               AND A.valA3 = B.valB3
               AND A.valA4 = B.valB4)
```

will return rows that are not in A and that are in B. If a row occurs 3 times in B and only 2 times in A it will not return one instance of that row, which is what I would need in order to bump up the occurence of that row in table A.

The query

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableB
```

doesn't work because if a row less in B than in A, I'll end up with the amount of that row that were in B, instead the amount that were in A.
Thanks!

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Do I need to change my question?

Comment: It got downvoted because that's what Stackover loves doing. Anyways, look into [INSERT INTO table SELECT ...](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). Your first case is trivial. The second one's going to be harder.

Comment: SO is not a substitute to get program or answers. You are expected to breakdown problems (find if X is true; if X is true do Y;)

Comment: @AjeetGanga Ok I'll keep that in mind thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same columns, and stich them together in one resultset?

Sounds like a [UNION ALL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm) and [EXCEPT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/except.php) can be used here.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableB
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=28b95468ac68c9e63aa0cde79054e8dd)*

But it has the disadvantage that it will result with the amount of duplicate rows as found in TableB.

And if you'd be able to use a Sqlite version (3.25+) that finally supports the window functions? [Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/releaselog/3_25_0.html).  Then using ROW_NUMBER can fix the problem of the "duplicates TableA > duplicates TableB" issue:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
    row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3, col4 order by (select 0)) as rn
  FROM TableA 
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
    row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3, col4 order by (select 0))
  FROM TableB 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 0
  FROM TableB
) q
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

*[test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=364ab8ba34b0b353213c7fb0859cf623)*

In older versions, the ROW_NUMBER window function can be mimicked.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
(
  SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4,
  (select count(*) from TableA a2
   where a2.col1 = a.col1 
     and a2.col2 = a.col2 
     and a2.col3 = a.col3 
     and a2.col4 = a.col4
     and a2.rowid >= a.rowid) as rn
  FROM TableA a
  EXCEPT
  SELECT b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, b.col4,
  (select count(*) from TableB b2
   where b2.col1 = b.col1 
     and b2.col2 = b.col2 
     and b2.col3 = b.col3 
     and b2.col4 = b.col4
     and b2.rowid >= b.rowid)
  FROM TableB b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 0
  FROM TableB
) q
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=f25ed9a0af7149401396cfe38100f612)*

Comment: I think this works for the example, but it seems that it doesn't work in general. EXCEPT won't select duplicate values

Comment: Hmm, I see. If a row occurs less in B (f.e. 2) than in A (f.e. 3), you'll end up with the amount of that row that were in B (f.e. 2). While you would still want to keep the max  amount of that row (f.e. 3). Maybe you should such sample rows to your question.

Comment: I've tried `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM TableB` and it works unless a row occurs in B more than once and does not occur in A. Then the row from B will only be added once

Comment: Yes I will do that!

Comment: @Mr.President for the second solution you'll have to wait for the next version 3.25.0.  The 3th solution mimics row_number() and should give the correct results.

Answer (score 2):

For *If a row occurs in B and not in A, add it to A.*, based on Shawn's comment:

```
INSERT INTO A (valA1, valA2, valA3, valA4)
SELECT valB1, valB2, valB3, valB4 FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT valA1, valA2, valA3, valA4
                 FROM A
                 WHERE A.valA1 = B.valB1
                   AND A.valA2 = B.valB2
                   AND A.valA3 = B.valB3
                   AND A.valA4 = B.valB4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although this definitely helps, it's not the full answer. If datatable B has 4 occurences of a row and datatable A has 3 occurances of the same row, I want to add the row once to datatable A. This query doesn't achieve that, if a row occurs more in B than it occurs in A, it is not selected.

Comment: Indeed, that is why I started with "For If a row occurs in B and not in A, add it to A., ..." :-)

Comment: What do you mean? Your query isn't complete? :)

Comment: No it only covers question no1.